# Data Fitting in Python for multiple peaks

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, least-squares, data-fitting

```
import numpy as np
from sympy.physics.wigner import wigner_6j
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xr=np.arange(0,33)
[Jo, Ju, I, Ao, Au]=[4.5, 4.5, 2.5,674.4,929]
Ao=Ao*0.00003335640954804
Au=Au*0.00003335640954804
xr1=100000000/np.array(xr)
positions=xr1
centroid = positions.mean(axis=0)
newo=0.005+100000000/4715.2274
Fo=[]
Fu=[]
new=[]
In=[]
Fomax=Jo+I
Fomin=abs(Jo-I)
Fumax=Ju+I
Fumin=abs(Ju-I)
no=int(2*min(Jo,I)+1)
for i in range(0,no):
    Fo.append(Fomax-i)
nu=int(2*min(Ju,I)+1)
for i in range(0,nu):
    Fu.append(Fumax-i)
for i in range(0,no):
    for j in range(0,nu):
        if abs(Fo[i]-Fu[j])<2:
            new.append(newo+(Ao/2)*(Fo[i]*(Fo[i]+1)-Jo*(Jo+1)-I*(I+1))-(Au/2)*(Fu[j]*(Fu[j]+1)-Ju*(Ju+1)-I*(I+1)))
            In.append((2*Fo[i]+1)*(2*Fu[j]+1)*(wigner_6j(Jo,Fo[i],I,Fu[j],Ju,1))**2/(2*I+1))
            max1=np.max(In)
for i in range(0,len(new)):
    for j in range(0,len(new)):
        if new[i]>new[j]:
            temp=new[j]
            new[j]=new[i]
            new[i]=temp
            temp=In[j]

            In[j]=In[i]
            In[i]=temp
zr=[]
sigma=0.031
x2=[]
y2=[]
y2r=[]
for i in range(0, len(new)):
    mew=new[i]
    for j in range(-100,100):
        c=mew+j/1000
        cc=In[i]*(1/(sigma*(44/7)**0.5))*np.exp(-1*((c-mew)/sigma)**2)
        y2.append(cc)
        x2.append(c)
max2=np.max(y2)
for i in range(0,len(new)):
    In[i]=In[i]/max1
for i in range(0,len(y2)):
    y2[i]=y2[i]/max2
for i in range(0,len(y2)):
    y2r.append(y2[i])
for i   in range(0,15):
    a=5
print(centroid)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x2, y2r,label="fitted data")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**I have this code which is making multiple peaks. The image 1 shows the data with multiple peaks overlapped with each other but i m trying to achieve only one curve by using these overlapped peaks as shown in image 2 in 'red' line. 
[image: This image is formed by running the program .]**

But the issue is that have to fit a line as shown in the last picture
[image: Red line is drawn by hand i want it to drawn by python]

Comment: One question is "what type of equation or model to use?" I think if you extract the max values for Y as you iterate across the X axis you would have data to be fitted, but fitted to what? I manually extracted such data points from your plot image, and even high-order polynomials are a poor fit. My only recommendation is to use a spline, which can fit such data, but the next question would be "is a spline sufficient for your requirements?" Splines are a  series of overlapping polynomials fitted to sections of the data - in effect, a segmented model with smooth joins between the segments.

Comment: Hi, may I ask: where is the fit? ...or say: what data to be fitted?

Comment: @JamesPhillips Gaussian model is what i want.. but at this stage any fit is highly appreciable. I dont know about splines but if u can do spline send me i will check it and see whether it is good for me or not..

Comment: @mikuszefski we have to fit the data.. the data of x-axis is given in "x2" and y-axis is "x2r" . The blue line is original data and in image 2 the red line is required. i made red line by hand. ;)

Comment: ...but the blue lines are constructed, right? And I guess the red line is supposed to be the sum of all blue lines. So what is to be fitted? Or is that supposed to be some generic data? Sorry that I still don't get it.

Comment: @mikuszefski look the blue lines are constructed by the program. the task is to fit the red line by using the blue lines data.

Comment: @mikuszefski summing/adding is not going to help.

Comment: So you have data ( not shown up to now ) which is a sum of several peaks, and you want to fit them. ... with peaks using Wigner_6j symbols. Is the number of peaks known? Can you give more insight on what your fit-function is? What would be the fit-parameters?

Comment: @mikuszefski if u run the program given above u will get the data by print(x2) and print(y2r) for values of x and y respectively. The number of peaks in this program is 16.... as fitting function which makes red line is good for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I get the question now. If I see it right the problem is basically that the `x` values differ. On top of it, everything is merged in a single list. To handle this I changed everything after `print(centroid)` to

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

def partition( inList, n ):
    return zip( *[ iter( inList ) ] * n )

xSplit = partition( x2, 200 ) ###manually set to 200 as data is created with range(-100,100)
ySplit = partition( y2r, 200 )
allx = sorted( x2 )
ally = np.zeros( len( allx ), np.float )
funcDict = dict()
for i in range( len( xSplit ) ):
    funcDict[i] = interp1d( xSplit[i], ySplit[i], kind='linear', bounds_error=False, fill_value=0 ) 
for i in range( len( xSplit ) ):
    ally += funcDict[i]( allx )

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot( allx, ally, linewidth=2 )
for col1, col2 in zip( xSplit, ySplit ):
    plt.plot( col1, col2, linestyle='--' )
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

which gives you

[image: sum vie interpolation]

which is the sum, but using interpolation of the data. Was that the idea?

**Edit**
Seems that the OP requires more an envelope rather than a sum. On solution is given by James Phillips. One can even shorten this using numpy changing

```
ally += funcDict[i]( allx )
```

to

```
ally = np.maximum(ally, funcDict[i]( allx ) )
```

which then gives

[image]

Comment: it looks good .. but when i am running this program it gives me error....
for i in range(len(xSplit)):

TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len()

Comment: i tried every thing but still the error persists.
''for i in range( len( xSplit ) ):
TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len()''
 How u run the code????

Comment: @Zewo your plot with the red line made me think the red line was to fit the maximum value , not the summed value. Which is better for your work?

Comment: To get rid of the type error, convert the zip objects to lists. I did this by changing line 76 from "funcDict = dict()" to "funcDict = dict();xSplit = list(xSplit);ySplit = list(ySplit)" using Python's semicolon operto to chain the commands so that I could put it in a comment here.

Comment: @JamesPhillips i was just trying to get the red line . summed value is bit deviated but if u can fit the maximum line it will be awesome..

Comment: @mikuszefski thanks for that .. it looks good to me.. but as u can see the superposition causes the overlap to increase by a certain amount.. suggested by james. i was actually looking for "maximum value" red line graph.........

Comment: My trivial change for max value in a different answer is based on this code, upvoted.

Comment: @Zewo I guess the zip error was a Python 2.7 ( I work with ) vs Python 3 ( you probably work with ) problem. Glad that James could help you out. I also updated the max part as there is a shorter version using numpy.

Comment: yes @mikuszefski i got it with the help of james ..thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Combining @mikuszefski code for summing with this code for max value might be what you are looking for, to use it replace everything after "print(centroid)" with:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

def partition( inList, n ):
    return zip( *[ iter( inList ) ] * n )

xSplit = partition( x2, 200 ) ###manually set to 200 as data is created with range(-100,100)
ySplit = partition( y2r, 200 )
allx = sorted( x2 )
ally = np.zeros( len( allx ), np.float )
funcDict = dict();xSplit = list(xSplit);ySplit = list(ySplit)
for i in range( len( xSplit ) ):
    funcDict[i] = interp1d( xSplit[i], ySplit[i], kind='linear', bounds_error=False, fill_value=0 ) 
for i in range( len( xSplit ) ):
    for j in range(len(allx)):
        ally[j] = max(ally[j],funcDict[i](allx[j])) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot( allx, ally, linewidth=2 )
for col1, col2 in zip( xSplit, ySplit ):
    plt.plot( col1, col2, linestyle='--' )
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Good point with the max and the help on `zip` for the OP. Guess it's a Python 2.7 Python 3 thing. Concerning the max I made an update using numpy's `maximum`. ...cheers.